# How to i get the filename of the current file if i have a function that does this in another php file?

Tags: php, html

I have this function to return the filename inside `useful.php`.

```
function filename(){
    return basename(__FILE__, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

I want to add `useful.php` using `include_once "useful.php";` to another file such as `index.php` and there I write something like this:

```
<a href="<?php print filename(); ?>?action=logout">Log Out</a>
```

It will show the filename of useful.php not this file:

```
<a href="useful.php?action=logout">Log Out</a>
```

How do I fix this. Thank you in advance. :)

PS: Sorry for the long title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is no simple solution, but you could use `debug_backtrace()` for that...

**1.php**

```
<?php
 include('2.php');
 echo filename();
```

**2.php**

```
<?php
function filename(){
    $bt = debug_backtrace();
    return basename($bt[0]['file'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

**Output**

`1.php`

---

OR change your function to this:

```
function filename($file){
    return basename($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
}
```

And use it in other files like this:

```
filename(__FILE__);
```